# Wordpress CPT extra parameter at the end of the URL -> 404

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, routes, custom-post-type

I've created a Custom Post Type. Collections See code below.

```
`$labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Collections', 'pcs' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Collection', 'pcs' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'New Collection', 'pcs' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'New Collection', 'pcs' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Collection', 'pcs' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Collection', 'pcs' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Collection', 'pcs' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Collections', 'pcs' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No Collection Found', 'pcs' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Collection Found in Trash', 'pcs' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Collection', 'pcs' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'All Collections', 'pcs' ),
        'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter collections list', 'pcs' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Collections list navigation', 'pcs' ),
        'items_list' => __( 'Collections list', 'pcs' )
    );`

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'show_in_menu'  => 'pcs',
        'menu_position' => 1,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'collections'),
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );
```

Works like a charm.
When I go to this page: http://www.example.com/collections/slug

it shows me the template thanks to a hook:

```
function xload_template( $single_template ) {

    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type == 'my_collection' ) {
        if ( file_exists( PATH . 'frontend/template.php' ) ) {
            $single_template = PATH . 'frontend/template.php';
        }
    }

    return $single_template;
}

add_filter( 'single_template', 'xload_template' );
```

The problem is, I want to pass an extra variable trough the url like this: http://www.example.com/collection/slug/email_md5

So I can use the email_hash as verification for viewing the collection. I know I have to make a url rewrite rule but I cannot get it working.

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('collections/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?collections=$matches[1]&email=$matches[2]','top');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

**FIX:** Since I was quite new to Custom Post Types within plugins from Wordpress I figured out it was much easier to create a rewrite if you know what Wordpress is doing. Change your wordpress settings-> Permalinks -> Plain. 
This way you can see how the url is called and how you need to use it within your own rewrites. The Answer below solved it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). You can try something like the following.

```
  function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('collections/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?collections=$matches[1]&email=$matches[2]','top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```